# HitBTC - Widgets

Tags: javascript

Example from: https://hitbtc.com/widget

How can I place 2 widgets at a time on one webpage? How I can "construct widget dynamically"?

```js
<div id="hitbtc-ticker" class="hit-medium" data-hue="28"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement("script");
        po.type = "text/javascript";
        po.async = true;
        po.src = "https://hitbtc.com/get_widget?pair=btcusd";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
     // You can construct widget dynamically by calling hitbtc.widget("myDiv", "medium", 28, "btcusd");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One [hitbtc](https://hitbtc.com/?ref_id=59aeac9f76e23) widget will work:

```html
<div id="hitbtc-ticker" class="hit-medium" data-refId="59aeac9f76e23"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement("script");
        po.type = "text/javascript";
        po.async = true;
        po.src = "https://hitbtc.com/get_widget?pair=ethbtc";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
     // You can construct widget dynamically by calling hitbtc.widget("myDiv", "medium", null, "ethbtc", "59aeac9f76e23");
</script>
```

Two widget will fail to show the second widget, because HTML cannot treat 2 objects with the same ID on one page:

```html
<div id="hitbtc-ticker" class="hit-medium" data-refId="59aeac9f76e23"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement("script");
        po.type = "text/javascript";
        po.async = true;
        po.src = "https://hitbtc.com/get_widget?pair=ethbtc";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
     // You can construct widget dynamically by calling hitbtc.widget("myDiv", "medium", null, "ethbtc", "59aeac9f76e23");
</script>

<div id="hitbtc-ticker" class="hit-medium" data-refId="59aeac9f76e23"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement("script");
        po.type = "text/javascript";
        po.async = true;
        po.src = "https://hitbtc.com/get_widget?pair=ethbtc";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
     // You can construct widget dynamically by calling hitbtc.widget("myDiv", "medium", null, "ethbtc", "59aeac9f76e23");
</script>
```

Trying to change the div id to any other id will result to a widget which cannot be loaded (css use id,childs after the widget is load: *#hitbtc-selector,#hitbtc-selector-label,#hitbtc-main-value* have unique id) , which force you have to keep `hitbtc-ticker` as div id

```html
<div id="hitbtc-ticker-A" class="hit-medium" data-refId="59aeac9f76e23"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement("script");
        po.type = "text/javascript";
        po.async = true;
        po.src = "https://hitbtc.com/get_widget?pair=ethbtc";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
     // You can construct widget dynamically by calling hitbtc.widget("myDiv", "medium", null, "ethbtc", "59aeac9f76e23");
</script>
```

To conclude:

As HTML cannot treat 2 objects with same ID on the same page, in my opinion, you cant place two widgets because the div id has to be different.

You may try to intercept (after the download) the script source then modify innerHtml before the evaluation to allow the use of differents id, but it is complicated and will not be acceptable from the [hitbtc side](https://hitbtc.com/?ref_id=59aeac9f76e23).

Regards